# Tool for comparing two versions of the same C++ function given the two source code files

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cvs

I have a C++ function `foo_bar` inside the source code file `lib.cpp`.

I am using a revision control tool (CVS for Windows) and I need to compare `foo_bar` between two different revisions of `lib.cpp`, is there any suitable tool for my need?

The tool should be able to properly locate `foo_bar` inside the two revisions because for example in one revision `foo_bar` is at the top of the file while in a different revision it is at the bottom of the file.

I am using Visual Studio but it is not integrated with CVS.

Thank you.

Comment: Why don't use plugins to integrate CVS & VS?

Comment: @Dewfy is there any plugin which allow me to do the comparison at *function* level?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with Araxis Merge. Open two revisions of `lib.cpp` and add **Synchronization Link** pointing to `foo_bar` in both revisions. On the other hand you can use any file comparison tool. Just paste two versions of `foo_bar` and compare them.

Comment: +1 Thank you, you understand the question :-) The Synchronization Link http://www.araxis.com/merge/topic_comparison_synchronization_links.html can help me even if I can't explicitly tell it "compare `foo_bar`"

Answer (score 0):

This is called a "diff tool".  The one that comes with VS sucks, as does WinDiff.

See this question for some opinions on the *best* such tools:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12625/best-diff-tool

Comment: How to integrate this tool into your environment is a separate question, and specific to the CVS client you are using ("CVS for Windows"?).  If you have this question, please ask it separately.

Comment: I know and use a diff tool but it lacks the capability of comparison at function level.

Comment: @uvts_cvs: The better ones allow you to select the correct lines to compare when a mismatch occurs, or do a better job of matching up lines.  Language knowledgeable diff tools will be harder to come by.  Most devs get by with just textual differencing.  If you need something more robust than this, then you might need to edit the question.  Also, think of this: With function overloading, modifying parameters, and deleting some functions, how would you detect which function was the correct one to diff?  It is a tough problem...

Answer (score 0):

http://tortoisesvn.net/downloads.html has a merge-tool which I think is very good.

Here is how to configure to use together with Visual Studio:
http://jeffhandley.com/archive/2010/03/08/tortoisemerge.aspx

I'm aware that you are using CVS and Tortoise is SVN but the merge-tool in tortoise is **very** good!

Comment: The OP is using CVS, not Subversion.

Comment: I'm aware that you are using CVS and Tortoise is SVN but the merge-tool in tortoise is very good!

Comment: There is a TortoiseCVS as well. I've never used it and I don't know whether it includes all/some/none of the handy tools of TortoiseSVN, but if TortoiseSVN has its own diff/merge tool (rather than just using whatever's in SVN) then it seems reasonable to me to hope that TortoiseCVS has it too.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.prestosoft.com/edp_examdiff.asp seems a good tool and I have had no problems with it.

Answer (score 0):

According to answer on my question, you hesitate about if diff tools could locate changes in particular functions.

Well, in 95% free tools (like examdiff) do it very well. Also try plugins listed there:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vssourcecontrol/thread/96cf363c-5324-475e-b249-85117a98c443